# How to remove the large space introduced by \nobibliography

Tags: bibliographies, citing, bibentry

I am using the **bibentry** package to list papers in my CV, but I find its "\nobibliography" cmd introduces huge unwanted space.

Use the package

```
\usepackage{bibentry}
```

Construct a bib file called "ref.bib" in the same directory as the tex file. Put in some references. Then use the following code,

```
I design and apply statistical models for following data mining/machine learning papers.
\nobibliography{ref}
blablabla...
```

The result is

> [image]

where "bla..." is where you put \bibentry items. The big space is ugly, is there any way to remove this? Or is there any other package that can help list papers from the bib file (without citing them)?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Did you run BibTeX? Have you tried placing the `\nobibliography` directive at the start of the document?

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to duplicate the extra space in a MWE. The code below produces the desired output when compiled with PDFLaTeX → BibTeX → PDFLaTex → PDFLaTeX on MikTeX 2.9.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\begin{document}
Here is some text.
\nobibliography{ref}
Here is some more text:
\bibentry{writer2012}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image: The code output does not have the undesired space]